# Remove part of a string in a java class

Tags: java, string

I have a string "undefined-undefined-2015-02-17". I want to remove all those "undefined-undefined-". Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: you should take look on String methods.Dont ask question without googling

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using [replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) method of String like:

```
String str = "undefined-undefined-2015-02-17";
System.out.println(str.replace("undefined-", ""));
Output:
2015-02-17
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to match the date.

```
if (str.matches("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}")) {
    ...
}
```

EDIT

Or a capturing group to extract the date.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("undefined-undefined-2015-02-17");
if (matcher.matches()) {
  String date = matcher.group(1);
}
```

Comment: what does `...` contain? That is the question asked by OP.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at String.substring() Javadoc

```
String date = "undefined-undefined-2015-02-17".substring( "undefined-undefined-".length())
```